# GSAP with react TweenMax giving error

Tags: reactjs, gsap, scrollmagic

I am trying to use GSAP with Scroll-magic inside a react component. My code is below

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import TopNavigation from '../pages/TopNavigation';
  import Footer from '../pages/footer';
  import $ from 'jquery';
  import ScrollMagic from 'scrollmagic';
  import {TweenMax} from 'gsap';
   import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

 class About extends Component {

componentDidMount() {
           var $this = $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this));

    this.handleLoad(this);
  }

  handleLoad(x) {
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var el1= $('#Menu');
        console.log(el1);
      var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
      var tween = TweenMax.to(el1, 0.5, {css:{opacity:0, top: -200}});
        /*
        var tween2 = Tween.to(".title-landing", 0.5, {scale:0});
        var tween3 = Tween.to(".top-nav-containerwrap", 0.4, {opacity:1});


        var scene1 = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
              triggerElement:"#fullwidthbg", //Selector or DOM object that defines the start of the scene
              triggerHook: 'onLeave', //sets the position of trigger hook w.r.t viewport
              duration:0, //The duration(in pixels) for which the element will remain sticky
              offset: 10 //Offset Value for the Trigger hook position
          })
          .setTween(tween);
           controller.addScene([
          scene1,

          ]);

          */


      });
   }
 render() {


return (
    <div id="Contact">
 <TopNavigation />
    Then rest of my code 
    where i have defined the elements that  i want to animate
```

It throws an error

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'to' of undefined"

pointing to line

```
var tween = TweenMax.to(el1, 0.5, {css:{opacity:0, top: -200}});
```

If you look at my code I have `console.log(el1)` to check if its getting the element and i am able to get the element details in the console

if I block this code the page runs smoothly.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Tough to say without seeing your project, but it sounds like you don't have TweenMax imported properly. Are you using the latest version? Maybe try doing import TweenMax from "gsap" instead (no braces). You could also try import TweenMax from "gsap/TweenMax". I assume you're using NPM, right? I also noticed that you've got some [commented out] code that references Tween.to() - I wonder if you meant TweenMax.to()?

Comment: I have tried the above but still the same error. I think Gsap is not getting imported correctly. I am using the gsap node library. How can i check if its getting imported and TweenMax is a function avaliable.

Also I was doing this {TweenMax as Tween} that is why i used tween there then i commented the lines

Comment: try to console.log('TWEEN MAX LOGING: ', TweenMax) and see the output to make sure it is defined

Comment: When i am using import {TweenMax} from "gsap" console.log(TweenMax) gives undefined as output when i do 
 import TweenMax from "gsap" output is {}

Comment: What version of TweenMax do you have installed? Have you done "npm install gsap"? What build system (or bundler) are you using? And you tried import TweenMax from "gsap/TweenMax", right?

Comment: I solved the issue by using the an alias in webpack. Was using create-react-app so had to eject first and then configure it now works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Spent bunch of time to find the solution that works for me.

Use CDN instead node module - include to your index.html in project public folder:

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/TweenMax.min.js" async="false"></script>`

It doesn't require import in react component. Use like:

```
 window.TweenMax.to(el1, 0.5, {css:{opacity:0, top: -200}});
```

Comment: Thanks Bud!! I solved the issue by using the an alias in webpack. Was using create-react-app so had to eject first and then configure it now works like a charm. But surely i will give your solution a try as well